# Is it possible to show the following inequality?

Tags: inequalities

Let $\phi\in C^s,0<\alpha\leq s<1$, where $C^s(0,T]$ is Holder continuous functions. Is it possible to show the following inequality
$$|\frac{\phi(x)}{x^\alpha}-\frac{\phi(y)}{y^\alpha}|\leq \frac{|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., let $\phi(u)=1$ for all $u$, and let $x\ne y$. Then the inequality fails to hold.

Comment: More generally, a good first step in assessing the viability of any inequality involving non-negative quantities is to check that the vanishing of the RHS implies the vanishing of the LHS.  (This is obviously a necessary condition for the inequality to hold, though it is far from sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks for you comment. This is much useful.